# Trigger parametrized job build using remote API through ajax

Tags: ajax, api, build, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins ver. 1.406 and can't get to trigger a parametrized (3 strings) build using AJAX.

Some docs talk about a "token" but there is no such option in Jenkin's OR job's configuration panels.

I'm sending the ajax call like this:

```
    var jqxhr = $.post(
    "http://servername:8080/job/jab-name/build/api/json",
    { "parameters": [{ "PARAM1": "value1" }, { "PARAM2": "value2" }] }, 
    "json"
)
.success(function () { alert("success"); })
.error(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert("Error\nxhr.status = [" + xhr.status + "]\n xhr.status: [" + xhr.statusText + "]\najaxOptions = [" + ajaxOptions + "]"); })
.complete(function () { alert("complete"); });
```

Parameters are correct (case sensitive) and all of them are set, not use of default value(s).

Anyone can help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A few things to check

1. Did you check the "Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)" option? If checked, there will be text box to enter your token.
2. Do you use security? If yes you have to authenticate against Jenkins.
3. Have a look at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API (The statement that you need to use json to trigger parametrized builds is wrong)

Comment: Hi; in the Jenkins job I try to run, no Trigger Build" option is enabled. There is no security at Jenkins nor server level (no basic/LDAP/Active Directory authentication request). I did try as the wiki page says in the example but it wasn't working either so I tried with the "/api/json" part in the url but that didn't help.

Comment: You _need_ to check "Trigger builds remotely" otherwise you are out of luck. AFAIK, you don't need to configure a token. then call http://server/job/myjob/buildWithParameters?PARAMETER=Value  or use the rest API. -- for reference see also https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to replace `build` with `buildWithParameters` in your URL.

```
var jqxhr = $.post(
    "http://servername:8080/job/jab-name/buildWithParameters/api/json",
    { "parameters": [{ "PARAM1": "value1" }, { "PARAM2": "value2" }] }, 
    "json"
)
.success(function () { alert("success"); })
.error(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert("Error\nxhr.status = [" + xhr.status + "]\n xhr.status: [" + xhr.statusText + "]\najaxOptions = [" + ajaxOptions + "]"); })
.complete(function () { alert("complete"); });
```

Comment: I tested now with the same result. It might be a cross site scripting issue but I am not sure.